# Node.js - how to set search path for server start js file.

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is in my app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));  /I know most app examples seem to use a 'views' directory instead. But I want to put more than views 

app.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.render('/pages/home');
});
```

then my folder structure looks like:

```
package.json
app.js
public
  index.html    //main html
  pages
    home.html    //one of a few html templates I load in using ngRoute
```

right now when it starts it gives this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/alex/node/pollstut/public/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

well of course. thats because app.js isn't in public, its in the root directory. I only want it to look for public stuff like html and js in the public directory. I want it to look for app.js in the project root directory. how can I tell it this?

Comment: Is it listening on port 3000? `app.listen(3000);`

Comment: I have app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
and then http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port),......

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTML files can be served by using express.static as they do not need a template engine. This will just serve the file without any processing (the same way you serve pictures or text files).

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I believe your error is that you're just setting the views path but you did not specify which engine to use. For example, you could use [.ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [.jade](http://jade-lang.com/) templates. There is an example [here](http://soohwan.blogspot.de/2011/02/nodejs-express.html).

Also, I see that you're just telling it to render /pages/home without specifying the file extension like you did with index.html.

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like it's generated before your app.js even gets launched. What command are you using to launch your server? My theory is that you are in the pollstut/public directory when you type node app.js. Try cd .. or whatever.

Further, Manuel is correct there- typically stuff in /views is dynamic template stuff, either ejs or jade or whatever other html template language is popular this week. When you call res.render, you're telling express to actually render a template rather than serve it.